# UITableView cell from nib - Can it be Dynamic? Also constraints - Arg

Tags: ios, swift, nib, uitableview

I have a nib for a tableview cell:

[image: nib]

Most of the time it will only require the top image, label and date.  Sometimes it will require the bottom image and label.

1. I have tried unsuccessfully to hide the bottom elements when I don't need them.  They hide just fine but the cell doesn't resize, leaving a huge, blank cell.  **How can I resize the cell when I need the bottom elements?**
2. I have tried every which way from Tuesday to constrain the top elements so the image stays centered between the top label and date label.  This is proving very difficult, especially when the label wraps 2 or 3 lines.  **Can anyone please provide guidance on how to pin these elements?**

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Give the optional image view and label a set height constraint and add an `IBOutlet` for those constraints. In `heightForRowAtIndexPath`, you can set the height constraints for those views to 0 if they should be hidden and the regular height if they should display. You will also need to return the calculated height of the cell in this method, based on whether or not you are hiding the optional views.